# Parenthesis in expr arithmetic: 3 * (2 + 1)

Tags: shell, quoting, arithmetic, expr

`expr` does not seem to like parenthesis (used in mathematics to explicit operator priority):

```
expr 3 * (2 + 1)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How to express operator priority in bash?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Another way to use `let` bash builtin:

```
$ let a="3 * (2 + 1)"
$ printf '%s\n' "$a"
9
```

**Note**

As [@Stéphane Chazelas pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149916/38906), in `bash` you should use `((...))` to do arithmetic over `expr` or `let` for legibility.

For portability, use `$((...))` like [@Bernhard answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149830/38906).

Comment: +1 Even more readable! I posted my question+answer just thinking it would be helpful for my fellow Linux users, but now I am getting a lot of benefit from the other answers :-)

Comment: There's no reason to be using `let`. It's not any more standard or portable than `(( a = 3 * (2 + 1) ))` (both come from `ksh` and are only available in ksh, bash and zsh) and it's less legible or easy to quote. Use `a=$((3 * (2 + 1)))` to be portable.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong, I'm just saying it should not be used as there are better alternatives (one for legibility `((a = 3 * (2 + 1) ))`, one for portability `a=$((3 * (2 + 1)))`), so it's not a note against you or your answer but against it being the selected answer and top-scorer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Updated my answer!

Comment: I have always used ```a=1 $[a+2]``` or ```a=1 b=2 $[a+b]```. Is their reason to avoid that syntax?

Comment: @Gordon: The bash man page says "The old format $[expression] is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash."

Answer (score 99):

You can use the arithmetic expansion instead.

```
echo "$(( 3 * ( 2 + 1 ) ))"
9
```

In my personal opinion, this looks a bit nicer than using `expr`.

From `man bash`

> **Arithmetic Expansion**
> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression and the substitution of the result.  The format for arithmetic expansion is:
>
> ```
>          $((expression))
> ```
>
> The expression is treated as if it were within double quotes, but a double quote inside the parentheses is not treated specially.  All tokens in the expression undergo parameter expansion, string expansion, command substitution, and quote removal.  Arithmetic expansions may be nested.
>
> The evaluation is performed according to the rules listed below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If expression is invalid, bash prints a message indicating failure and no substitution occurs.

Comment: Aside from readability, it also doesn't require forking an extra process to do the arithmetic; it's handled by the shell itself.

Comment: Note that in POSIX shells, it's subject to word splitting, so it's a good habit to quote it in list contexts.

Comment: When I try this at the bash shell I get 'Illegal variable name."

Answer (score 45):

There's no reason to be using `expr` for arithmetic in modern shells.

POSIX defines the `$((...))` expansion operator. So you can use that in all POSIX compliant shells (the `sh` of all modern Unix-likes, dash, bash, yash, mksh, zsh, posh, ksh...).

```
a=$(( 3 * (2 + 1) ))
a=$((3*(2+1)))
```

`ksh` also introduced a `let` builtin which is passed the same kind of arithmetic expression, doesn't expand into something but returns an exit status based on whether the expression resolves to 0 or not, like in `expr`:

```
if let 'a = 3 * (2 + 1)'; then
  echo "$a is non-zero"
fi
```

However, as the quoting makes it awkward and not very legible (not to the same extent as `expr` of course), `ksh` also introduced a `((...))` alternative form:

```
if (( a = 3 * (2 + 1) )) && (( 3 > 1 )); then
  echo "$a is non-zero and 3 > 1"
fi
((a+=2))
```

which is a lot more legible and should be used instead.

`let` and `((...))` are only available in `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash`. The `$((...))` syntax should be preferred if portability to other shells is needed, `expr` is only needed for pre-POSIX Bourne-like shells (typically the Bourne shell or early versions of the Almquist shell).

On the non-Bourne front, there are a few shells with built-in arithmetic operator:

- `csh`/`tcsh` (actually the first Unix shell with arithmetic evaluation built-in):

  ```
  @ a = 3 * (2 + 1)
  ```
- `akanga` (based on `rc`)

  ```
  a = $:'3 * (2 + 1)'
  ```
- as a history note, the original version of the Almquist shell, as posted on usenet in 1989 had an `expr` builtin (actually merged with `test`), but it was removed later.

Comment: I learn something new every day from you, Stéphane. I very much appreciate your POSIX shell knowledge!

Comment: How about `: $((a = a*2))`?

Comment: What if I have a floating point? My expression is a=$(( -14 + 0.2 * (1+2+3) )). The error token is ".2*(1+2+3)"

Comment: @Blaise, then you'd need a shell that supports floating points in `$((...))` like zsh, ksh93 or yash.

Comment: @Blaise If you need floating point, you can just use an external program, like so `a=$(bc <<<"-14 + 0.2 * (1+2+3)")`

Answer (score 19):

`expr` is an external command, it is not special shell syntax. Therefore, if you want `expr` to see shell special characters, you need to protect them from shell parsing by quoting them. Furthermore, `expr` needs each number and operator to be passed as a separate parameter. Thus:

```
expr 3 \* \( 2 + 1 \)
```

Unless you're working on an antique unix system from the 1970s or 1980s, there is very little reason to use `expr`. In the old days, shells didn't have a built-in way to perform arithmetic, and you had to call the `expr` utility instead. All POSIX shells have built-in arithmetic via the [arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_006_004) syntax.

```
echo "$((3 * (2 + 1)))"
```

The construct `$((…))` expands to the result of the arithmetic expression (written in decimal). Bash, like most shells, supports only integer arithmetic modulo 2<sup>64</sup> (or modulo 2<sup>32</sup> for older versions of bash and some other shells on 32-bit machines).

Bash offers an [additional convenience syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) when you want to perform assignments or to test whether an expression is 0 but don't care about the result. This construct also exists in ksh and zsh but not in plain sh.

```
((x = 3 * (2+1)))
echo "$x"
if ((x > 3)); then …
```

In addition to integer arithmetic, `expr` offers a few string manipulation functions. These too are subsumed by features of POSIX shells, except for one: `expr STRING : REGEXP` tests whether the string matches the specified regexp. A POSIX shell cannot do this without external tools, but bash can with `[[ STRING =~ REGEXP ]]` (with a [different regexp syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) — `expr` is a classic tool and uses BRE, bash uses ERE).

Unless you're maintaing scripts that run on 20-year-old systems, you don't need to know that `expr` ever existed. Use shell arithmetic.

Comment: `expr foo : '\(.\)'` also does text extraction. `bash`'s `BASH_REMATCH` achieves something similar. It also does string comparison, which POSIX `[` does not do (though one could imagine ways to use `sort` for that).

Comment: underscore as syntax placeholder --- you a Schemer, @Giles ? :]

Comment: @RubyTuesdayDONO I didn't use an underscore here. Are you misreading U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS? If so, try using a bigger font.

Comment: @Giles — okay, yes, it only looks like an underscore because of my font size. for me, "Schemer" is a complement, and it's not like ellipsis versus underscore changes the meaning anyway … no need to get snarky over it :/

Answer (score 15):

Use parenthesis with quotes:

```
expr 3 '*' '(' 2 '+' 1 ')'
9
```

The quotes prevent bash from interpreting the parenthesis as bash syntax.

Comment: What Nicolas illustrates but doesn’t explain is that the tokens on the `expr` command line must be separated by spaces; so; for example, `expr 3 "*" "(2" "+" "1)"` ***will not work***. (Also, BTW, you probably don’t need to quote the `+`.)

Comment: The parentheses aren't keywords like `while` and `[[`, they're syntax. If they were keywords, they wouldn't be interpreted as such in command arguments. You need quotes so that bash doesn't parse them but instead sees a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

If you have bc..

```
echo '3 * (2 + 1)'|bc 
9
```

Answer (score 0):

If Tcl is available, then you can "ask" it to perform computation within one line command.
I am quite limited by `tcsh` in my environment (only integer arithmetic). Example of the solution I found:

```
echo "puts [expr {(2.1+2**3) / 3}]; exit;" | tclsh
3.3666666666666667
```

For me it serves the need, when float numbers/**parenthesis**/advanced operations required.