# bash: -eq vs. == and `bc` output type

Tags: bash, test, arithmetic, bc

This snippet of code has been taken from a larger script, (humbly) simulating the non-existing `abs()` function:

```
[[ $(echo "$val < 0" | bc) -eq 1 ]] && val=$(echo "$val * -1" | bc)
```

So we test the number whether it is negative; if yes the second statement after the `&&` will be executed.
This was my original line.

Some other SE user later changed this into:

```
(( $(bc <<<"$val < 0") == 1 )) && val=$(bc <<<"$val * -1")
```

OK, though both of these apparently work, I still prefer mine as it does not only make use of the `-eq` operator (which has been implemented *especially* for non-strings) but it also avoids here-strings, which makes the code work better on read-only environments. (Keep in mind that `/tmp` MUST be writeable for here-strings to work.)

Lastly, I seem to remember that `bc` in the later line will output a true integer, which makes the use of `==` rather questionable, since this is only recommended to be used for strings.
Unfortunately `bc` does not reveal in its `man` page either whether it outputs its results as plain numbers or strings.

Opinions?

Comment: If the number is always integer, why don't you just `abs=${val#-}`?

Comment: Just never thought of that, thanks for the inspiration. :) I'm a `bash` old-schooler and still not too familiar with the "modern" `${...#...}` syntax using brace substitution.

Comment: @syntaxerror; note that (not all but) this sort of variable expansion is even defined in POSIX.

Comment: It may be noteworthy that `ksh` supports `abs(x)` in arithmetic contexts.

Answer (score 2):

You have confused here.

Both `[[ $(echo "$val < 0" | bc) -eq 1 ]]` and `(( $(bc <<<"$val < 0") == 1 ))` used integer comparison.

`((..))` is equivalent to `let` builtin in `ksh`, `bash` and `zsh`. It evaluated [arithmetic expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic). Inside `((..))`, all operators and their precedence, associativity, and values are the same as in the C language.

The one make you confuse was `==` inside new test operator `[[...]]`. When `==` available, it's equivalent with `=` and perform pattern matching. You need to double quotes either sides for doing string comparison `[[ "$a" == "$b" ]]`.

Comment: Well, thanks for the explanation, but in fact I didn't "confuse" anything. I simply was unsure, hence I chose to ask. Plus, I wasn't able to determine the `bc` output type. Whatever, in the `bash` manual page, there was nothing written explicitly about the `==` being used for numbers - only for strings.

Comment: @syntaxerror: You have confused with `==` in `((..))` and `==` in `[[...]]`. Inside `((..))`, `==` is arithmetic operator, it performed integer comparison. I invite you to read http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149823/38906

Comment: Can we agree that the manual is a bit too less clear and verbose on this matter still? ;)

Comment: @syntaxerror: It has documented clearly. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs and http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic