# "Unexpected end of File" Returned from BASH Script

Tags: bash

Not sure why I am getting this. I realize this must be a common question, but can't figure it out.

```
#!/bin/bash
 #Checks word count of each text file directory and deletes if less than certain   amount of words
 #Lastly, displays number of files delter

 count = 0 #Set counter to 0
 limit = 2000

 for file in *.txt
 do
     words = wc -w > $file
     if words < $limit
         rm $file
         count = $count + 1
     end
 end

 print "Number of files deleted: $count"
```

Comment: You may want to learn `csh` instead.

Comment: this piece of code burns my eyes !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid your script is full of syntax errors. The specific error you are seeing is because you're not closing the `for` loop correctly, but there are many, many more:

1. You can't have spaces around the `=` when assigning values to variables (except in arithmetic expressions);
2. In order to save a command's output in a variable, you must use [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst), either `` var=`command` `` or `var=$(command)`;
3. When referring to the value of a variable, you must use `$var`, not `var` and generally, that needs to be quoted (`"$var"`);
4. When doing an [arithmetical comparison](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html), you need to use the `-lt` of the `[` command, not `<` unless you're using double parentheses;
5. The `command > file` format will overwrite `file` with the output of command. You probaly meant to use `wc < "$file"` and not `wc > $file`;
6. You can't add a value to a variable using `var=$var+1` unless that variable has been previously declared as an integer, you need `((var=var+1))`, `var=$((var+1))` or `declare -i var; var=var+1`. For adding 1, you can also use `((var++))`;
7. Your `if`syntax is wrong. The right format is `if condition; then do something; fi`
8. Same goes for the `for` loop, the right syntax is `for loop-specification; do something; done`;
9. There is no `print` command (not built in bash anyway), only `printf` and `echo`;
10. You should [always quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222) unless there is a good reason not to.

So, a working version of your script with slight improvements, would be:

```
#!/bin/bash -
# Checks word count of each text file directory and deletes if less than certain   amount of words
# Lastly, displays number of files deleted

count=0 # Set counter to 0
limit=2000

for file in *.txt
do
     words=$(wc -w < "$file")
     if [ "$words" -lt "$limit" ]
     then
         rm -- "$file"
         ((count++))
     fi
done

echo "Number of files deleted: $count"
```

Next time, I recommend you familiarize yourself with a language before attempting to code in it. Each language has its own rules and syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a RA who has to do a crack jobs on a lot of these programming things. Good at the logic but not the syntax. Many thanks.

Comment: @stéphane great edit, as always. Could you explain why you prefer `((var++))` over `let var++`?

Comment: [more legible, usually (not here) shorter, consistent with `((...))`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149916).

Comment: Hmm, why not `if ((words < limit))` then? @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @Arthur2e5, yes. Personaly, I'd do `[ "$words" -lt "$limit" ]` and `count=$((count + 1))` so it can be a standard sh script as there's no need for bash here.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop terminators are incorrect. A `for` loop is terminated by `done`, not `end`. Likewise, the `if` condition is terminated by `fi`, not by `end`.

This is Bourne/POSIX-family shell syntax. Other shells may indeed have those two things terminated by `end`, but `bash` does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
words = wc -w > $file
```

the `>` char here seems out of place. Without it you would be counting the lines of `$file` but as it stands you are counting the line of stdin and outputting the result in `$file`.