# Usage example of let expression in bash

Tags: bash

While I'm searching for `bash` examples, I find the `let` command but I never understand it.

I saw the `man bash`, also I couldn't understand  what `let` expression does.

Some `let` usage that I saw:

- `let z=z+3`
- `let "z += 3"`

What is the usage of `let`?

Any explained example will be appreciated.

Comment: I invite you to read http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149823/38906

Comment: thank you !  so according to your question there , is let a="3 * (2 + 1)" replaces a=$((3  *  $((2 + 1)))) , and is it meant to do only such job ?...

Comment: They did the same job, and `let` is the same as `((...))`. You should read Stephane answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149916/38906 for more detail.

Comment: oh yeah i was reading it , and i got it !    many thanks bro :3